# How to rename file without date and time

Tags: linux, rename

I need to remove date and time from below mentioned files. I will receive these files on daily basis. So I have to remove the date and time stamp from file name and rename them.

File names

```
Sds_api_anp_bta_full_20190807_20190807003027.dat
Sds_api_anp_currency_full_20190807_20190807003027.xml
```

Please suggest.

Comment: What is the expected result? Will you do it manually or should it be done by a cronjob? please provide a [minimal reproducaple example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to try to solve your own problem first. Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For further information, please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question, and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the site.

Comment: Sds_api_anp_bta_full.dat this is expected output... I will receive multiple files similar. Need to create bash script to rename the file.

Answer (score 0):

You could use two easy commmands with wildcard

`mv Sds_api_anp_bta_full_*.dat Sds_api_anp_bta_full.dat`

`mv Sds_api_anp_currency_full_*.xml Sds_api_anp_currency_full.dat`